# appStoreReceiptURL on mainBundle always returns nil

Tags: ios, objective-c, in-app-purchase

This method appStoreReceiptURL is the replacement for the deprecated transactionReceipt method on SKPaymentTransaction.  And everyone says to just use this call instead:

```
NSURL *theURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] appStoreReceiptURL];
```

This is supposed to return a url to a receipt if there is one.  But for me there isn't one, as this value is nil, and as far as I can tell it shouldn't be.  I'm running on iOS 7 and have done a few in-app purchases (sandbox on the device).  Now I'm trying to add another in-app purchase, an auto-renewing subscription, and I need to dig into the receipt to get the subscription expiration date.  But I can't get past this simple step because the value is simply always nil.

Does anyone know why?

Comment: Strange. Under iOS 7 that method should never return `nil`. There may be no file at the URL but the URL should always have a value.

Answer (score 24):

A bit late, but it may be of use to someone:

```
-(void) someMethod {
    NSURL *receiptUrl = [[NSBundle mainBundle] appStoreReceiptURL];
    if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:[receiptUrl path]])
    {

        NSData *ios7ReceiptData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:receiptUrl];
        //Do stuff

    } else {
        NSLog(@"iOS 7 AppReceipt not found %@, refreshing...",iapID);
        SKReceiptRefreshRequest *refreshReceiptRequest = [[SKReceiptRefreshRequest alloc] initWithReceiptProperties:@{}];
        refreshReceiptRequest.delegate = self;
        [refreshReceiptRequest start];
    }
}

- (void)requestDidFinish:(SKRequest *)request {
    if([request isKindOfClass:[SKReceiptRefreshRequest class]])
    {
        //SKReceiptRefreshRequest
        NSURL *receiptUrl = [[NSBundle mainBundle] appStoreReceiptURL];
        if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:[receiptUrl path]]) {
            NSLog(@"App Receipt exists");
            //Do stuff
        } else {
            NSLog(@"Receipt request done but there is no receipt");

            // This can happen if the user cancels the login screen for the store.
            // If we get here it means there is no receipt and an attempt to get it failed because the user cancelled the login.
            //[self trackFailedAttempt];
        }
    }
}
```

`

Comment: Thanks for your tip ! but I need to check if users already buy the app. have you suggestion ?

Comment: Wrong, don't do it. Refresh might request the user and pass, and Apple explicitly says that it should happen only by a user action.

Answer (score 1):

It's now iOS 8.4 and Xcode 6.4 so maybe history is different, but I find this method call always returns nil when running in the simulator.  On a real device it works as documented by Apple: The path to where the app receipt is intended to be stored is returned -- with no guarantee that either there is a receipt there nor that it is a valid receipt.

Comment: I suppose it could have been that, but it's been so long now I no longer remember. :)