# appStoreReceiptURL Error

Tags: ios, objective-c, in-app-purchase

I can't understand why it does not enter into the if control. Anyone knows explain to me?

```
- (void)verifyapp{
    NSURL *receiptURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] appStoreReceiptURL];

    NSLog(@"%@", receiptURL);
    //CONTROLLO SE ESISTE

    if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:receiptURL.path]) {

    }
}
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20027322/appstorereceipturl-on-mainbundle-always-returns-nil/21020440#21020440

Answer (score 8):

Receipt only exist if you install app from the AppStore. If you install it from the XCode Debug mode, it will not have a receipt. To debug your code you need to install app from AppStore first, launch it and install app from XCode above it.