# How long is the in-app-purchase receipt file stored locally on the user device?

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase, app-store

The receipt file at `NSBundle.mainBundle().appStoreReceiptURL` is stored after an In-App-Purchase or upon a `SKReceiptRefreshRequest`.

For how long is the file then stored on the device and available for validation?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20027322/appstorereceipturl-on-mainbundle-always-returns-nil

Comment: @SamB How does the other question relate to this question?

Comment: @EricD I don't think that this is the right place for meta-discussions. Swift is the code language used in the question, so the tag seems appropriate to me. However, if you'd like to start a meta question on this, I would be very interested to see the outcome.