# iOS- In app purchase working proper in sandbox environment, Appstore version content not unlocked

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

In-app purchase working in the sandbox environment but in Appstore version amount debited from user account but the content is not unlocked.

I don't think there is an issue in coding. otherwise, it will not work in the sandbox environment. I think it may possible that transaction receipt is nil.

When I click to purchase again that it shows "you have already subscribed". But still, it's not unlocking app content. Even I clicked to restore the purchase but its also not working. I surprised why everything is working in the sandbox environment.

Subscription type: auto-renewable. 
Content unlocking: Audio, video and pdf tutorials .
I have checked backend log. API never executed and the only issue I fill is that I did not get app store receipt even if the user purchased successfully. everything working perfectly in sandbox environment.

Code:

```
public func paymentQueue(_ queue: SKPaymentQueue, updatedTransactions transactions: [SKPaymentTransaction]) {

        for transaction in transactions {

            switch transaction.transactionState {
            case .purchasing:
                handlePurchasingState(for: transaction, in: queue)
            case .purchased:
                handlePurchasedState(for: transaction, in: queue)
            case .restored:
                handleRestoredState(for: transaction, queue: queue)
            case .failed:
                handleFailedState(for: transaction, in: queue)
            case .deferred:
                handleDeferredState(for: transaction, in: queue)
            }
        }
    }

//On transaction state changed to purchased:
func handlePurchasedState(for transaction: SKPaymentTransaction, in queue: SKPaymentQueue) {
        print("User purchased product id: \(transaction.payment.productIdentifier)")
        print("User purchased product id: \(transaction)")
        queue.finishTransaction(transaction)
        self.completeTransaction(transaction:transaction)
    }

//In completeTransaction Method:
func completeTransaction(transaction:SKPaymentTransaction)
    {
        if let receiptURL = Bundle.main.appStoreReceiptURL,FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: receiptURL.path)
        {
            let receipt:Data = try! Data(contentsOf: receiptURL)
            let jsonObjectString = receipt.base64EncodedString(options: Data.Base64EncodingOptions(rawValue: 0))
            var strIdentifier:String = transaction.transactionIdentifier!

            if let identifier = transaction.original?.transactionIdentifier
            {
                strIdentifier = identifier
            }

        //API call to save receipt to validate later and unlock the content
        //In case API calling failed then I stored data and called API again on app home page.
        }
    }
```

Comment: We need more detail: what type of IAP is this, what type of content is it unlocking and post your code. Generally unlocking the content is your apps responsibility, so I would not rule out a coding issue!

Comment: I have edited the question with what you have asked. Please check. Thanks.

Comment: OK, so have you tried refreshing the receipt using refreshReceiptRequest as described in the answer to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20027322/2466193)

Comment: Yes, That's not the case. I have added logs to everywhere in the code and upload the new build to store. Now I have checked the logs, There is no problem with receipt. when I make the purchase the payment queue delegate method called and user's amount is deducted from the account. But the transaction.transactionState returns failed. why is that happening?

Answer (score 0):

Please finish the transaction after you verify the receipt queue.finishTransaction(transaction)

apple also recommends that "Download all Apple-hosted content before finishing the transaction. After a transaction is complete, its download objects can no longer be used."

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/Chapters/DeliverProduct.html